# Error while importing xls file - Java Application

Tags: java, apache, azure, xlsx, rhel

I have a Java based Web application that i am running in Microsoft Azure.
OS: RHEL 7.3 Version. 
Web Server: Apache 9
So issue is when uploading a .xlsx file then it is giving me following error. Also on every other infra (including AWS, local) with same configuration, every thing is running fine. I am confuse where can be the error i.e. AT Server level configuration or error in Java Application code?

> HTTP Status [500] – [Internal Server Error]
>
> Type Exception Report
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented > it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.vspl.asp.interceptors.SessionInterceptor.intercept(SessionInterceptor.java:40)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
>       org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
>       org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>       org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>   Root Cause
>
> java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
>   Exception Details:
>     Location:
>       com/monitorjbl/xlsx/impl/StreamingSheet.getPaneInformation()Lorg/apache/poi/ss/util/PaneInformation; @4: areturn
>     Reason:
>       Type 'org/apache/poi/hssf/util/PaneInformation' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'org/apache/poi/ss/util/PaneInformation' (from method signature)
>     Current Frame:
>       bci: @4
>       flags: { }
>       locals: { 'com/monitorjbl/xlsx/impl/StreamingSheet' }
>       stack: { 'org/apache/poi/hssf/util/PaneInformation' }
>     Bytecode:
>       0x0000000: 2ab6 0117 b0
>
> com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingWorkbookReader.loadSheets(StreamingWorkbookReader.java:160)
>       com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingWorkbookReader.init(StreamingWorkbookReader.java:132)
>       com.monitorjbl.xlsx.impl.StreamingWorkbookReader.init(StreamingWorkbookReader.java:91)
>       com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader$Builder.open(StreamingReader.java:263)
>       com.vspl.asp.util.ReadR2Excelsheet.noOfRows(ReadR2Excelsheet.java:57)
>       com.action.gstr2.ReturnsGstr2Action.readFile(ReturnsGstr2Action.java:161)
>       com.action.gstr2.ReturnsGstr2Action.loadExcelFile(ReturnsGstr2Action.java:141)
>       com.action.gstr2.ReturnsGstr2Action.uploadInvoices(ReturnsGstr2Action.java:112)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:441)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:280)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:243)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:165)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:252)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:122)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:195)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:179)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:89)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:130)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:126)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:138)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:87)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:165)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:179)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       com.vspl.asp.interceptors.SessionInterceptor.intercept(SessionInterceptor.java:40)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:306)
>       com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:237)
>       org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
>       org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:488)
>       org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
>       org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
>   Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.

Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M21

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I was using Apache POI hssf library to process .xlsx file. You can check in error. It should be "xssf" version.

Reference Link: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/